# Why is VSCode launching node, instead of TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a TypeScript file in VSCode that I'm trying to debug.

When I launch it, VSCode launches "node CheckFMBackup.ts", instead of calling TypeScript on CheckFMBackup.ts first, before calling "node CheckFMBackup.js".

Why doesn't VSCode call "node CheckFMBackup.js", instead, it calls "node CheckFMBackup.ts"?

Did I configure something wrongly? The reason I know node is called, instead of TypeScript, is in the screenshot below. I've enabled breakpoints on checked and unchecked exceptions.

CheckFMBackup.ts:

```
    const BITQUERY_API_URL = "";
    const BITQUERY_API_KEY = "";
    const axios = require("axios");
    
    async function makeRequest(query: string) {
        const result = await axios.post(BITQUERY_API_URL, {
            query: query,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-API-KEY": BITQUERY_API_KEY
            }
        });
      
        return result.data;
    }
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\CheckFMBackup.ts",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json", 
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    "target": "es2017",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2020",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "./out",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could edit your `preLaunchTask`. You should give a name for the task like following on your `launch.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            ...
            "preLaunchTask": "tscBuild"
        }
    ]
{
```

And in your `tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "tscBuild",
            "command": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            ...
      
        },
}
```

Comment: How does changing the build task name make VSCode launch node?